# django oscar ImportError raised when trying to load 'treebeard.templatetags.admin_tree': No module named util

Tags: django, django-oscar

When installing the django-oscar on MAC. The make oscar complains

```
Django Version:     1.9
Exception Type:     InvalidTemplateLibrary
Exception Value:    

Invalid template library specified. ImportError raised when trying to load 'treebeard.templatetags.admin_tree': No module named util
```

Comment: too early for django1.9 ;)

Answer (score 0):

Django 1.9 is not compatible yet. Suggest using django 1.8. So just uninstall django 1.9

`pip uninstall django`

then install lower version of django

`pip install "django<1.9"`

and it work.

Answer (score 0):

If you run the sample projects just change the command from:

```
$ make sandbox
```

to:

```
$ make install
$ pip install Django==1.8.7
$ make build_sandbox
```

and it will work